# Xpath - multiple tags with same name starting with a substring

Tags: xpath

I have this XML file and I need to get the name and the author/s of a book, where name of at least one author starts with "E".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE library SYSTEM  "knihy.dtd">
<library>
<book isbn="0470114878">
    <author hlavni="hlavni">David Hunter</author>
    <author>Jeff Rafter</author>
    <author>Joe Fawcett</author>
    <author>Eric van der Vlist</author>
    <author>Danny Ayers</author>
    <name>Beginning XML</name>
    <publisher>Wrox</publisher>
</book>
<book isbn="0596004206">
    <author>Erik Ray</author>
    <name>Learning XML</name>
    <publisher>O'Reilly</publisher>
</book>
<book isbn="0764547593">
    <author>Kay Ethier</author>
    <author>Alan Houser</author>
    <name>XML Weekend Crash Course</name>
    <year>2001</year>
</book>
<book isbn="1590596765">
    <author>Sas Jacobs</author>
    <name>Beginning XML with DOM and Ajax</name>
    <publisher>Apress</publisher>
    <year>2006</year>
</book>
</library>
```

I tried this approach

```
for $book in /library/book[starts-with(author, "E")]
return $book
```

but it returns XPathException in invokeTransform: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of starts-with() ("David Hunter", "Jeff Rafter", ...). So how can I check this sequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message suggests, use `starts-with()` in predicate *for individual `author` elements*, instead of passing all `author` child elements to `starts-with()` function at once :

```
for $book in /library/book[author[starts-with(., "E")]]
return $book
```

**<kbd>[`xpathtester demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/04aa145881d3b460a882d38369bf86b1)</kbd>**

The above will return all `book`s where name of at least one of the `author` starts with `"E"`.

**output :**

```
<book isbn="0470114878">
    <author hlavni="hlavni">David Hunter</author>
    <author>Jeff Rafter</author>
    <author>Joe Fawcett</author>
    <author>Eric van der Vlist</author>
    <author>Danny Ayers</author>
    <name>Beginning XML</name>
    <publisher>Wrox</publisher>
</book>

<book isbn="0596004206">
    <author>Erik Ray</author>
    <name>Learning XML</name>
    <publisher>O'Reilly</publisher>
</book>
```

Comment: Right, and this simplifies to `/library/book[author[starts-with(., "E")]]`, which'll work with XPath 1.0 too.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the return statement. I had to return the authors with the book as well => for $kniha in /knihovna/kniha[autor[starts-with(., "E")]]
return $kniha/autor/concat(., " - ",$kniha/nazev)